# Deleting log directories of a particular timestamp in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I want to delete directories that are five days old, based on the directory name, instead of unix timestamp.
Let us assume that directories are created like `test_2013-05-20-12:23:43` and so on.

I want to delete all directories that are 5 days older, i.e before the 16th.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not specific with file name criteria use this

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

Note that there are spaces between rm, {}, and \;

Explanation

The first argument is the path to the files. This can be a path, a directory, or a wildcard as in the example above. I would recommend using the full path, and make sure that you run the command without the exec rm to make sure you are getting the right results.
The second argument, -mtime, is used to specify the number of days old that the file is. If you enter +5, it will find files older than 5 days.
The third argument, -exec, allows you to pass in a command such as rm. The {} \; at the end is required to end the command.

read this [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/) for more info

Comment: It is showing error like   find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]

Comment: find logTest/logTest_* -mtime +5 rm { } \;

Comment: Thanks Zigma, But +5 means it is deleting 7 days past files instead of 5 days.

Comment: The question said not to use mtime, but instead the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky, first of all find out the unix epoch of 5 days ago

```
$ date --date='5 days ago' +%s
1368599762
```

and then you can parse each directory name, extract the time part, transform it in a unix epoch time and compare if are before that date; if yes delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames are using ISO-8601 formatting as in your example, it's fairly easy to just do a lexical comparison:

```
oldest=`date -d 'today -5 days' '+test_%F-%T'`
find "$log_dir" -name 'test_*' -print \
  | while read f; do test "$f" '>=' "$oldest" || rm "$f"; done
```

(untested; assumes filenames don't include newlines)

This is a great fringe-benefit of standardizing on ISO-8601. :-)